# I ADB 1.0.32 not working in windows 10

Tags: android

I previously used ADB version 1.0.31 for Windows 10. It is working fine. My Asus Zenfone 5 have problem in startup. I need to Update my firmware via ADB. But it ask ADB Version 1.0.32 or newer to sideload the device. When I installing ADB 1.0.32 it not even started. It gives follow error when type 'adb devices' command. Help me to solve this.

```
adb server is out of date.  killing...   
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: protocol fault (no status)
```

I installed and updated all the driver. But still i have problem.

Answer (score 1):

I also had issues earlier today with my ADB installation, so I removed all the drivers and installed ADB 1.0.32 via this software called "15 seconds ADB installer v1.4.2".

Read more about it here and try it out: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2588979 
Download the version **1.4.2** of the installer

This software fixed the issues for me, who's also running Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone put a `.\` before your command. For example `adb sideload lineage-16.0-20190624-nightly-klte-signed.zip` returned to me the you need ADB 1.0.32 or newer to sideload to this device. Put `.\` in front of it it worked.